# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mention'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i want to mention the variable (that saving the username),this is my code

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def book(ctx,stage,low,high):
    channel = bot.get_channel(642826606858993707)
    author = '{0}'.format(ctx.message.author)
    await ctx.send(f'{author.mention}')
```

that will get the error:AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mention'.

so how can i fix it?thanks

Comment: Once you do this `author = '{0}'.format(ctx.message.author)` the `author` object is at that point of type `str` (string) and you can no longer use it to access any other fields in whatever your `ctx` object is (hence your error message). It seems like you are relatively new to programming. I would recommend researching "debuggers" and "debugging Python code". This will allow you to better understand your objects (like the `ctx` object) and what you want to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I quickly want to get out of the way to improve your code slightly,

`pass_context` is no longer needed since discord.py no longer has a rewrite and non-rewrite version. The `command` is explained in more detail within the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#discord.ext.commands.command).

You have used both `.format` and `f` strings in your code. Sticking to one would make it much easier to understand.

You assigned the variable channel, but never seemed to actually use it, unless you committed some of your code.

Onto the error,
To mention the author of the message, you converted the author into a string, hence why you are getting this error. To mention a user, you can simply send a message with [.send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.TextChannel.send) and mention the user directly with [.mention](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=user%20mention#discord.User.mention).

```
async def book(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention)
```

Hope that helps!